# Bash redirection inside command

Tags: bash

Why is Bash producing two different outputs for these two commands:

```
$ echo $(tput cols 2>/dev/null)
80
$ echo $(tput cols)
141
```

PS. Widen your terminal to have more than 80 columns (most shells default to 80).

Comment: I can't reproduce this, you're going to have to provide more information.

Comment: Cant reproduce either: echo $(tput cols)   -> 80

Comment: You'd need to widen your terminal to have more columns than 80, and than it's reproducible.

Comment: I've updated question to reflect this.

Comment: That's "redirection" not "pipe".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be because both stdout and stderr have been redirected, so `tput` doesn't know what terminal you want the info for.

```
$ tput cols >out; cat out       # works because stderr is still the terminal
118
$ tput cols 2>err               # works because stdout is still the terminal
118
$ tput cols >out 2>err; cat out # lost track of the terminal, going with default
80
```

Note that in your example, stdout is redirected implicitly by `$()`.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that it gets implicitly redirected.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this problem is

```
$ max_width=`stty -a | sed -n '/columns/s/.*columns \([^;]*\);.*/\1/p' 2>/dev/null`
```

stty is better way to do what you want!

Comment: may be this is new: `stty size 2>/dev/null |cut -d" " -f2`